# Visual studio coded ui tests do not read initialize

Tags: selenium, webdriver, initialization, visual-studio-2013, coded-ui-tests

I have written a coded UI test with a set of test methods and a test initialize. I have selenium webdriver installed and run an instance of it in the initialize. In each following method however, the driver is not recognized, and I need to set a new driver instance for each test.

What can I do to make each test method recognize the driver instance in the initialize, so that I don't have to place a driver instance in each test?

Answer (score 0):

Put the driver instantiation into a [TestInitialize] method in a Base class, and then make each test class inherit from the Base class.